svelte transition:slide is jumpy when component switch with different height happen
i have a two forms, one for sendOTP and the other one for verifyOTP and the verify otp one is taller than the send otp. the height transition for my container is jumpy on getting back from second form to first one.
i've used transition:slide to smoothly change the height, but when i'm going back from second form to first one the slide goes to the height of verify otp form(the taller one) and jump to the height of first form. i've used fly transition as well but same issue persisted, at first i wanted a transition from right to left between forms with fly transition x: -300, x: 300 but not working on height.
this is my code:
<div class="flex overflow-hidden"
     transition:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}>
    {#if !$showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full"
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
        >
            <SendOtpForm on:success={handleLoginSuccess} />
        </div>
    {:else if $showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full"
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
        >
            <VerifyOtpForm {phoneNumber} on:back={handleBackToSendOtp} />
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>


Try the following:
To your Script tag add:
<script>
    // bind the height of your two forms
    let sendOtpHeight
    let verifyOtpHeight
    
    // Reactively switch the height of the container using the same
    // condition as the {#if} block
    $: containerHeight = !$showOtpForm ? sendOtpHeight : verifyOtpHeight
</scritp>

In the HTML part, bind the client heights of the wrappers and inline the height of the container concatenating the containerHeight value. Add a transition to the height and it should grow and shrink smoothly.
<div class="flex overflow-hidden"
     style="height: {containerHeight}px; transition: height 0.6s ease-in-out"
     transition:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}>
    {#if !$showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full"
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            bind:clientHeight={sendOtpHeight}
        >
            <SendOtpForm on:success={handleLoginSuccess} />
        </div>
    {:else if $showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full"
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            bind:clientHeight={verifyOtpHeight}
        >
            <VerifyOtpForm {phoneNumber} on:back={handleBackToSendOtp} />
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>

The issue may persist because during the switch both wrappers are children of the container. To fix that, add position:relative to the container and make both wrappers position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0. Something like this:
<div class="flex overflow-hidden"
     style=" height: {containerHeight}px; 
             transition: height 0.6s ease-in-out;
             position:relative;
           "
     transition:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}>
    {#if !$showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full form-wrapper"
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            bind:clientHeight={sendOtpHeight}
        >
            <SendOtpForm on:success={handleLoginSuccess} />
        </div>
    {:else if $showOTPForm}
        <div
            class="min-w-full form-wrapper"
            in:slide={{ duration: 500, delay: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            out:slide={{ duration: 500, easing: circInOut }}
            bind:clientHeight={verifyOtpHeight}
        >
            <VerifyOtpForm {phoneNumber} on:back={handleBackToSendOtp} />
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>

<style>
.form-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>



thanks for your input, i think the issue is exactly that when the transition is happening both components are still inside the container, when i added containerHeight, the switch does not happen, after sendOtp form slide, the verify otp form dont show(i wasn't able to debug), i don't know what the problem, and about  setting the positions absolute, the forms go outside the container and not show at all, i think the absolute positioning might be the solution, but don't know how to properly use it, any explicit input would be much appreciated.

Right, I see. It may not have applied the containerHeight switch because I made a mistake when using the "showOTPForm" by not auto-subscribing to it properly with $showOTPForm, I fixed that in the answer. The absolute positioning in CSS will let you set the position relative to the nearest parent who has a explicit position: relative style. So in the new code I added those styles that will basically attach both forms to the top left corner of the container and the svelte transitions will happen relative to that final positioning
